# Jest tests in SWR - Next.js project - how to test error and isMutating?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, jestjs, swr

I have a component that shows conditionally components based on the value of `error` and `isMutating`.

```
  const { trigger: theLoginTrigger, error, isMutating } = useTheLogin();
```

And here is the hook:

```
import useSWRMutation from "swr/mutation";
import moment from "moment";
import { axios } from "@/utils/pathToApiClientWithInterceptor";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { z } from "zod";

const validatePasswordWithoutUpperCase = new RegExp(
  "^(?=.*[0-9])([...regex...]"
);

export const loginSchema = z.object({
  email: z.string().email("Please enter a valid email"),
  [...]
});

export type LoginPayload = z.infer<typeof loginSchema>;

const fetcher = async (url: string, { arg }: { arg: LoginPayload }) => {
  try {
    const { data } = await axios.post(url, arg);
    return data;
  } catch (e) {
    throw e;
  }
};

const useTheLogin = () => {
  const router = useRouter();

  const { trigger, error, isMutating } = useSWRMutation("/login", fetcher, {
    onSuccess: (response: { token: string }) => {
      router.push("/");
    },
  });

  return {
    trigger,
    error,
    isMutating,
  };
};

export { useTheLogin };
```

Please help. I have tried also to mock the function, but `error` and `isMutating` are not being read by the component. I tried spyOn, but it gives `TypeError: Cannot redefine property: useTheLogin at Function.defineProperty (<anonymous>)`

I am wondering what is the best/easiest way to change `error` and `isMutating` during the test, to pass to the component the values I want.

Can anyone please help?